# Calculating maximum number of consecutive decrease in value in recent 6 months

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

| PID | XID | Name | StatementDate | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Person A | Trans 1 | Account 1 | 2015-04-30 | 100 |
| Person A | Trans 1 | Account 1 | 2015-05-31 | 0 |
| Person A | Trans 2 | Account 2 | 2015-04-30 | 1000 |
| Person A | Trans 2 | Account 2 | 2015-05-31 | 900 |
| Person A | Trans 2 | Account 2 | 2015-06-30 | 800 |
| Person A | Trans 2 | Account 2 | 2015-07-31 | 700 |
| Person B | Trans 3 | Account 3 | 2015-04-30 | 200 |
| Person B | Trans 3 | Account 3 | 2015-05-31 | 100 |
| Person B | Trans 3 | Account 4 | 2015-04-30 | 700 |
| Person B | Trans 3 | Account 4 | 2015-05-31 | 800 |
| Person B | Trans 3 | Account 4 | 2015-06-30 | 600 |
| Person B | Trans 3 | Account 4 | 2015-07-31 | 1000 |

In the above table, I am trying to find out the maximum consecutive decrease for each Account Name in the recent 6 months and append it to the dataset (as below, the rows which have missing Balance).

| PID | XID | Name | StatementDate | Balance | IsDecreasing | ConsecDecrease | MaxConsecutiveDecreaseL6M |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Person A | Trans 1 | Account 1 | 2015-07-31 |  |  |  | 0 |
| Person A | Trans 1 | Account 1 | 2015-04-30 | 100 | FALSE | 0 |  |
| Person A | Trans 1 | Account 1 | 2015-05-31 | 0 | TRUE | 1 |  |
| Person A | Trans 1 | Account 1 | 2015-07-31 |  |  |  | 3 |
| Person A | Trans 2 | Account 2 | 2015-04-30 | 1000 | FALSE | 0 |  |
| Person A | Trans 2 | Account 2 | 2015-05-31 | 900 | TRUE | 1 |  |
| Person A | Trans 2 | Account 2 | 2015-06-30 | 800 | TRUE | 2 |  |
| Person A | Trans 2 | Account 2 | 2015-07-31 | 700 | TRUE | 3 |  |
| Person B | Trans 3 | Account 3 | 2015-07-31 |  |  |  | 1 |
| Person B | Trans 3 | Account 3 | 2015-04-30 | 200 | FALSE | 0 |  |
| Person B | Trans 3 | Account 3 | 2015-05-31 | 100 | TRUE | 1 |  |
| Person B | Trans 3 | Account 4 | 2015-07-31 |  |  |  | 2 |
| Person B | Trans 3 | Account 4 | 2015-04-30 | 700 | FALSE | 0 |  |
| Person B | Trans 3 | Account 4 | 2015-05-31 | 800 | TRUE | 1 |  |
| Person B | Trans 3 | Account 4 | 2015-06-30 | 600 | TRUE | 2 |  |
| Person B | Trans 3 | Account 4 | 2015-07-31 | 1000 | FALSE | 0 |  |

The data I have is [PID, AccountName, StatementDate, Balance].

The columns I'm trying to create is [IsDecreasing, Consecutive, MaxConsecutiveDecreaseL6M], with the last field as the ultimate goal.

I'm trying to do this with pandas but I'm having issue finding out the Balance of previous months to determine whether the Balance has decreased from M-1 to M , for each AccountName (for every month in the recent 6 months).

Anyone has any idea to do this via python/pandas?

**Edit:**

I have successfully gotten the desired columns and values with the below code by looping through each row in the dataframe.
But it is taking quite a long time as I have around 86k rows.
Is there any other way to do it which could shorten the computing time?

P.S. Assuming that the name of dataframe which I have loaded the first table as 'joined_df'.

```
# Compute Max Consecutive Decrease in recent 6 months

# Create IsDecreasing column
for idx in joined_df.index:
    # Skipping first row as there is no previous row to compare to
    if idx == 0:
        continue

    # If 'PID', 'XID', 'Name' matches with previous row, check whether the 'Balance' is higher than previous row (next month)
    if (joined_df.loc[idx, ['PID', 'XID', 'Name']] == joined_df.loc[idx - 1, ['PID', 'XID', 'Name']]).all():
            if ((joined_df.loc[idx, 'Balance']) - (joined_df.loc[idx - 1, 'Balance'])) > 0:
                joined_df.loc[idx, 'IsDecreasing'] = True
            else:
                joined_df.loc[idx, 'IsDecreasing'] = False
    else:
        joined_df.loc[idx, 'IsDecreasing'] = False

# Create ConsecDecrease column
for idx in joined_df.index:
    # Skipping first row as there is no previous row to compare to
    if idx == 0:
        continue

    # Initialize variable
    consec_decrease = 0
    
    # Loop back to previous rows (maximum 5 rows back, i.e. 5 months)
    # If 'PID', 'XID', 'Name' matches, compute the Consecutive Decrease for each row.
    if (joined_df.loc[idx, ['PID', 'XID', 'Name']] == joined_df.loc[idx - 1, ['PID', 'XID', 'Name']]).all():
        if joined_df.loc[idx, 'IsDecreasing'] == True:
            for n in range(6):
                if joined_df.loc[idx - n, 'IsDecreasing'] == True:
                    consec_decrease += 1
                else:
                    # Break the loop if IsDecreasing becomes False in previous record
                    break
        else:
            consec_decrease = 0
    
    # Convert ConsecDecrease column type to integer
    joined_df.loc[idx, 'ConsecDecrease'] = int(consec_decrease)


# Create MaxConsecBalanceDecreaseL6M column
reference_month = datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 31)
reference_month_begin = reference_month.replace(day = 1)
reference_month_end = reference_month + dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(day = 31)
l6m = reference_month_begin - dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months = 5)

max_consec_decrease_s = joined_df[(l6m <= joined_df['StatementDate']) & (joined_df['StatementDate'] <= reference_month_end)] \
                   .groupby(['PID', 'XID', 'Name'])['ConsecDecrease'].max()

consec_decrease_df = max_consec_decrease_s.rename('MaxConsecBalanceDecreaseL6M') \
                                          .reset_index()

consec_decrease_df['StatementDate'] = reference_month

# Append MaxConsecBalanceDecreaseL6M column into main dataset
final_df = joined_df.append(consec_decrease_df, ignore_index = True, sort = False)
```

Comment: Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.